# API endpoint /activities doesn't return historical activities (only very recent ones are accessible)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Here is the oldest page I can scroll down for activities.list API for TEDx Talks channel

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&channelId=UCsT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q&maxResults=50&pageToken=CPoBEAA&fields=items(snippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken%2CprevPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and response is

```
{
    "prevPageToken": "CPoBEAE",
    "items": [
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-21T18:30:36.000Z",
             "title": "You Are Not Who They Think You Are | Vinny McCoy | TEDxDrogheda"
           }
       },
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-21T18:27:43.000Z",
             "title": "What does it mean to be authentic? | Sarah Archer | TEDxDrogheda"
           }
       },
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-21T18:27:33.000Z",
             "title": "Moments in Jazz |  Jazz Quartet of the Conservatory of the Polyphonic Choir of Patras | TEDxPatras"
           }
       },
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-20T20:14:23.000Z",
             "title": "Moments in Jazz |  Jazz Quartet of the Conservatory of the Polyphonic Choir of Patras | TEDxPatras"
           }
       },
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-21T18:22:57.000Z",
             "title": "Adriano Teixeira | Adriano Teixeira | TEDxPassoFundo"
           }
       },
       {
           "snippet": {
             "publishedAt": "2017-11-21T18:21:50.000Z",
             "title": "Eargasm - Beat Box Act by Ivory Parker aka neXor | Ivory Parker | TEDxDonauinsel"
           }
       }
  ]    
}
```

You can see that there is no nextPageToken that means you can't scroll further, and the oldest activity has

```
"publishedAt":  "2017-11-21T18:21:50.000Z"
```

Meanwhile, there is at least this video

```
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=xzA-QZ0yqJg
```

published  2017-10-24.

**UPD**: Reported issue case was fixed on Youtube API side.

Comment: Is it fro that channel?

Comment: Yes you can check `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=xzA-QZ0yqJg&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2FchannelId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` And you will see `{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCsT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q"
   }
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: It is not a activity probable.

Comment: Other videos publishings are, so it should be, probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interrogating `activities` which is returning a list of `"kind": "youtube#activity"` and the item you are providing as an example is listed as `"kind": "youtube#video"`. If you would use the `video` endpoint rather than `activities`  you will find that item too.

**UPDATE**

It looks like there is a limit of historycal activities that are served by the call.
I succeed browsing the activities by specifying `publishedBefore` parameter. The pagination will bring you a lot further.

Eg.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=UCsT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q&maxResults=50&pageToken=CGQQAA&publishedBefore=2017-10-25T18%3A21%3A50.000Z&fields=items(snippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Date used can be, obviously, something in the future to cover everything.

Comment: That's true but if this video is published, there should be an activity for this, and I'm interested in activities. The video is the only one example that this channel is active, has 10M subscribers and should have activities before 2017-11-21. So again, the main issue is that activities are missed, not that I'm interested in data about video.

Comment: It looks like specifying the `publishedBefore` may help you retrieve historical activities: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=UCsT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q&maxResults=50&publishedBefore=2016-11-21T18%3A21%3A50.000Z&fields=items(snippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Here is the activity related to the video you have mentioned: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=UCsT0YIqwnpJCM-mx7-gSA4Q&maxResults=50&pageToken=CGQQAA&publishedBefore=2017-10-25T18%3A21%3A50.000Z&fields=items(snippet(publishedAt%2Ctitle))%2CnextPageToken&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Yeap this was helpful, thanks! Hope the whole API will be fixed later.